# Calculated column for IF not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have created a calculated column to see if the target has been met. I have tried different combinations of IF formulas. Am I  missing something? Thank you

```
=IF([Response date]=0,"Not met",IF([Days to complete]>=[Estimated response (days)],"Not met",IF([Days to respond]<=[Estimated response (days)],"Met")))
```

```
=IF([RESPONSE DATE]=0,"NOT MET",IF([DAYS TO COMPLETE]>=[ESTIMATED RESPONSE (DAYS)],"NOT MET","MET"))
```

[image: SharePoint list - target met column is not calculated properly. Days to respond > estimated response days = Not met]

Answer (score 0):

For the first formula, the last if statement, `IF([Days to respond]<=[Estimated response (days)],"Met")` , you only provide one branch. The syntex of IF function shall be like

```
IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

And for the second formula it seems fine and works in my end
[image]
[image]

Are you using number column for both days column?

**Update: Column settings and result**

[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I have checked that the columns are set to number. I fixed the first formula, that didn't work. I copied the second formula, that didn't work. I deleted the calculated column and re-added it, and it's still not working. Both formulas are still not working.

Comment: I tried a different formula ```=IF([Days to complete]>=[Estimated response (days)],"NOT MET","MET")```. This is the ![result](https://imgur.com/a/Qumxh5k).

Comment: @doughnut, then it may be better for you to check the column settings, like column type. Because it seems what ever the value is, the condition is always false. May be one of the column is in fact a single text column

Comment: These are the settings for the fields. [Calculated column](https://imgur.com/a/Ig2n2TN), [Estimated response date](https://imgur.com/a/ok9ebxB), [Days to respond](https://imgur.com/a/3gMyhEb), [formula](https://imgur.com/a/CMVyyeJ), and [output](https://imgur.com/a/pHaRC3h). I'm not sure what else I can try.

Comment: @doughnut, It seems I find the root cause. The formula in Estimated Response returns a wrong value. You shall use 5 instead of "5" as the return value (so as "10"). "5" will be treated as a string instead of a number even you set the return value as number.

Comment: I removed all " " from the return values. However, it did not change anything.  I updated [DAYS TO RESPOND to capture weekdays](https://imgur.com/a/FXYsDak), and Target Met formula is ```=[Days to respond]<=[Estimated response (days)]```. With these changes, I am still getting the  [same outputs](https://imgur.com/a/yx0x9Rt).

Comment: @doughnut, just curious about why updating the Days to Respond. And You have updated the formula in Estimated response date column and nothing changes? My set up is updated in the original reply and works fine.

Comment: @doughnut, And for troubleshooting, what we can do now will be ruling out all the elements one by one.  Use a If statement with condition only concerning one element, like Days to respond>80 to test. Ensure that the value of that column can be compared correctly. Carry out the process for all concerning columns.